# HTML Merge Cells Form

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following structure that I should create as HTML Table. At first it seems easy for me but when I have tried to build it, it took me a lot of time with no satisfactory result. Please take a look at the image below to see the type of table that I want to create.

[image]

I have tried to create as follows but no luck.

```html
    <table>
    <caption>Browsers by Visitors</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Head One</th>
        <th colspan="3" rowspan="2">Head Two</th>
        <th colspan="3">Head Three</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Head Four</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Head Five</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Sub1</th>
        <th>Sub2</th>
        <th>Sub3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Sub1</th>
        <th>Sub2</th>
        <th>Sub3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
        <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

The above code doesn't work. Please someone help here...

Comment: The data in the image that you showed is different from what you have coded. Can you make another image that has the same data like the one in your HTML, to make things easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here it goes:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Head One</th>
      <th colspan="3">Head Two</th>
      <th colspan="3">Head Three</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Head Four</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Head Five</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Sub1</td>
      <td>Sub2</td>
      <td>Sub3</td>
      <td>Sub1</td>
      <td>Sub2</td>
      <td>Sub3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>s</td>
      <td>s</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>asd</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>asdasd</td>
      <td>asdasd</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CCC</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>asdas</td>
      <td>dsafsd</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DDD</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>sd</td>
      <td>s</td>
      <td>asdasd</td>
      <td>asddasdf</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>     
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>     
    </tr>
</table>
```

Do try to read more on `colspan`, `rowspan`, `th`, `tr`, `td`, `table` collapsed borders [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). I removed the `thead` and `tbody` in your code.